# Move a row in mysqli into another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables one named Contacts and one named Repairs.

here is the contents from Repairs

```
id
name
phone
address
budget
due
```

in contacts i have the following columns

```
id
name
phone
address
```

is there a way to sync the 2 tables for certain rows?

```
name
phone
address
```

i am looking for a way to add a button that will move and valadate to make sure its not already done on the rows in Repairs of

```
name
phone
address
```

I do not want to delete the row in repairs

the code for the button i have so far is

```
<a href="add_to_contacts.php?id#<?php echo$id; ?>Add to Contacts</a>
```

But i not a clue on what to have in my add_to_contacts.php

i would thought it would be something like

```
    <?php    
    include 'db_connect.php';

function move_row($id = 0) {
    $query = $this->db->query('select * from repairs where id = ' . $id);
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $this->db->insert('contacts',$name);
}
?>
```

Please not the last bit of code is what i got so far it might be a million miles away but all i can say is i tried.

What would be the right code to use here?

Update

this is the new code

```
<?php    
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';



$query = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone, address) SELECT name, phone, address FROM repair_jobs
                    where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'
                    limit 0,1";

                    ?>
```

Comment: what is this `$action = INSERT INTO cotacts SELECT * FROM repairs;` thing?

Comment: i done some looking around on the net and like i said i try to do it myself before seeking help or advice

Comment: Beside any other fact, I think @YourCommonSense is trying to point you out, that the string is not a valid PHP string, since it's not quoted

Comment: Not only. it is a *part* of the right approach, however incomplete and used nowhere in the code

Comment: would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: nevertheless, your idea of syncing is wrong. There should be NO  contacts information in the Repairs table, but in contacts table only

Comment: @YourCommonSense i have updated my question how could i adapt this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone, address) SELECT name, phone, address FROM repairs WHERE id = $id
```

Like this:

```
<?php    
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone, address) 
          SELECT name, phone, address FROM repair_jobs 
          WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."' 
          LIMIT 0,1";

$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense How?

Comment: @YourCommonSense What exactly this mean? About `id = $id`?

Comment: is this right? <?php    
    //include database connection
    include 'db_connect.php';
    


$query = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone, address) SELECT name, phone, address FROM repair_jobs
                        where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'
                        limit 0,1";
      
      ?>

Comment: Yes. And run the query.

Comment: i have pasted this in a php names copytest.php then went to copytest.php?id=56 (which is a valid entry id) nothing happens

Comment: Could you paste to your above question footer whole codes in `copytest.php`?

Comment: @RickNash Where is your `$mysqli->query($query);`? You have to run query

Comment: lol thanks :) lets tidy this question up paste the right code to your answer or re answer it :)

Answer (score 2):

Really this should be a comment - but it's a bit long.

The question is fundamentally flawed.

The elephant in the room here is that your data schema is wrong. You shouldn't be holding the same data in 2 different tables - that's why it's called a RELATIONAL database. The repairs table should contain:

```
id
budget
due
contact_id
```

Where contact_id refers to a record in the contacts table.

In your question, you've not provided any details of how you match the data you intend to copy into the contacts table to avoid creating duplicate records.

Comment: that is very true. i am still trying to pick these things up.

the idea of your answer in great but how would i achieve this. and display the data relating to the repairs?

Comment: please post a link on information regarding this as im very intrested

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878 or just type the magic words into google.